# Как решить задачу калькулятор на питон

Tags: python

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту задачу, и ход мыслей желательно

> ...34... Введение в динамическое программирование. Python
> Калькулятор
> Имеется калькулятор, который выполняет три операции:
>
> - прибавить к числу X единицу;
> - умножить число X на 2;
> - умножить число X на 3.
>
> Определите, какое наименьшее число операций необходимо для того, чтобы получить из числа 1 заданное число N.
>
> Примеры
>
> *Ввод 1*
> 32718
> *Вывод*
> 17
>
> *Ввод 2*
> 1
> *Вывод*
> 0

Вот мой код:

```py
a = float(input())

count = 0

while a != 1:

    if (a % 2 == 0 or a % 3 == 0):
        if (((a - 1) % 9 == 0) and a % 16 != 0):
            a = (a - 1)/9
            count += 3
        else:
            if ((a - 1) % 32 == 0):
                a = (a - 1)/32
                count += 6
            if (a % 16 == 0):
                a = a/16
                count += 4
            if (a % 16 != 0 and a % 2 == 0):
                a = a/2
                count += 1
            if (a % 9 == 0 or a % 3 == 0):
                a = a/3
                count += 1
    else:
        if a != 1:
            a = a - 1
            count += 1
        if a == 1:
            break
print(count)
```

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://tproger.ru/articles/dynprog-starters/). Там есть разбор вашей задачи.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Надо придумать функцию которая решает задачу и запрограммировать её.

*f<sub>n</sub>* - минимальное чиcло шагов для получения *n* из единицы. Что про неё можно сказать?

- *f<sub>1</sub> = 0* - это, я думаю, объяснять не нужно.
- *f<sub>k+1</sub> ≤ 1 + f<sub>k</sub>* - потому что *f<sub>k+1</sub>* не может быть больше, иначе нарушится требование минимальности (обоснование опущено, но вы должны это хорошо понимать);
- *f<sub>2k</sub> ≤ 1 + f<sub>k</sub>* - следущее правило, обоснование аналогично;
- *f<sub>3k</sub> ≤ 1 + f<sub>k</sub>* - аналогично.

Все условия переведены на язык формул. Вычисление *f*:

- *f<sub>1</sub> = 0*
- если *k* делится на *2* и на *3* то *f<sub>k</sub> = 1 + min(f<sub>k-1</sub>, f<sub>k/2</sub>, f<sub>k/3</sub>)*
- если *k* делится на *2* и не делится на *3* то *f<sub>k</sub> = 1 + min(f<sub>k-1</sub>, f<sub>k/2</sub>)*
- и так далее ...

Код:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    v = f(n - 1)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        v = min(v, f(n // 2))
    if n % 3 == 0:
        v = min(v, f(n // 3))
    return v + 1


print(f(int(input())))
```

Для маленьких *n* работает хорошо, после сотни тормозит, для больших чисел падает с переполнением стека. Теория хороша, практика не очень.

Проблема в том что мы очень много раз вычисляем одни и те же значения *f<sub>n</sub>*. Можно сделать оценку, что количество вызовов растет как *e<sup>n</sup>*. Чтобы избавится от повторных вызовов, значения функции надо запоминать в кэше:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    v = f(n - 1)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        v = min(v, f(n // 2))
    if n % 3 == 0:
        v = min(v, f(n // 3))
    return v + 1


print(f(int(input())))
```

Кэш всё ускоряет, но проблема с глубиной рекурсии остаётся. Чиним её: вычисляем значения *f* последовательно от единицы до *n*, вычисленные значения храним в списке `cache` и используем по необходимости. Рекурсии нет и нет проблем с её глубиной:

```
def f(n):
    cache = [0] * (n + 1)
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        v = cache[i - 1]
        if i % 2 == 0:
            v = min(v, cache[i // 2])
        if i % 3 == 0:
            v = min(v, cache[i // 3])
        cache[i] = v + 1
    return cache[-1]


print(f(int(input())))
```